# cordova.exec strange behaviour in parameters

Tags: java, android, plugins, cordova

Using cordova 2.6, i am calling a plugin using cordova.exec.
The issue is that the parameters if passed in an array element are being cut(truncated from the end by some characters) at the java side.
but if i pass a simple string as a parameter its being passed perfectly fine.

> Passed 5714 characters in string and its going without any isues, but passing 450 characters in an array's first element is cutting the array into about 1/4th of its original length(119) .

Then tried the following :

> 1. Converted the first array element into string.(Checked the typeof using javascript) and passed but did not help.
> 2. Created a substring of the original array and passed static limits to the substring i.e substring(0,4000) etc etc, but to no luck.
> 3. Made a clone of the original array and repeated steps 1 and 2 but again no luck.

Could someone tell me where the issue is?

> Increased eclipse heap memory and changed to cordova 2.8.1 too, but the same result. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason for the behaviour. Inspected many images , and in my execute method of plugin did the following :

```
int myLength = args.getString(0).length();
Log.v(TAG,Character.toString(args.getString(0).charAt(myLength-1)));
```

Got the character as **=** on the plugin/java side. And an = is inserted in the base64 string at the end of it. It seems that cordova is inserting these delimeters in the base64string.

> P.S. :Went through phonegap.js and found that the arguments are being packed as JSON.stringify , and after that could not get more. That how and where the = is inserted.